# Login With Spotify Button: Using HTML and php

Tags: php, html, spotify

I am trying to figure out how to access a user's Spotify OAuth token when they click on a "Login With Spotify" button on a website. I am having difficulty figuring out how to have the user click on a button, and then redirect them to the Spotify authentication website, and then come back to my website and get their spotify OAuth token. I can only use HTML and php due to a server limitation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a site to get help with your existing code, not to help you design something that you haven't yet designed.  
If you don't have current code, nor do you know how you'd design this on paper regardless of code implementation, then you need to do some [additional research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), make an attempt and, if you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried.

Comment: Here's a link to get your started with a PHP library: https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php